# Need help to fix error during Jenkins iOS build

Tags: ios, jenkins

PLATFORM AND VERSION
iOS
Mac OS Monterey
Xcode 13.1

DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM
We are seeing issues with running ioS builds from Jenkins. The following is the code signing error we get. Any pointers on the nature of error will help. It worked well on Mac OS Catalina and Xcode 12.3.

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign B4AE2D1F9FA44C8A8F3758D96E3DD94E7F9E3DF8 --preserve-metadata\=identifier,entitlements,flags --generate-entitlement-der /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxx-glufhfbxmahajqgxjgbpunechgwo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxxxxx/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/MiSnapSDKMibiData.framework
/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxx-glufhfbxmahajqgxjgbpunechgwo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxxxxx/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/MiSnapSDKMibiData.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
CodeSign /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxx-glufhfbxmahajqgxjgbpunechgwo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxxxxx/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/TrustDefender.framework (in target 'xxxxxx' from project 'xxxxxx')
CodeSign /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxx-glufhfbxmahajqgxjgbpunechgwo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxxxxx/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/MobileFlow.framework (in target 'xxxxxx' from project 'xxxxxx')
CodeSign /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxx-glufhfbxmahajqgxjgbpunechgwo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxxxxx/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/MiSnapSDKScience.framework (in target 'xxxxx' from project 'xxxxxx')
CodeSign /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-glufhfbxmahajqgxjgbpunechgwo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxxxxx/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/xxxxxx.app/Frameworks/MiSnapSDKMibiData.framework (in target 'xxxxx' from project 'xxxxxx')
(4 failures)
```

STEPS TO REPRODUCE
The following is the build script executed.

```
xcodebuild -workspace mobile/platforms/ios/xxxxx \
-scheme xxxxxx -configuration Release archive \
-archivePath mobile/platforms/ios/xxxxx.xcarchive \
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=xxxxx \
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=xxxxx \
CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual \
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION=xxxxx \
MARKETING_VERSION=xxxxx
```